# Resizing a canvas element when browser window size changes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a web page with the following layout using React:

- A top bar
- A side bar on the right
- A canvas element filling the remaining screen space

The elements should fill the page width and height exactly and respond to change of the browser window size.

I can achieve this behavior using a flexbox, but the canvas content is extremely blurry.

This can be solved by setting the canvas resolution to it's dimensions inside an `useEffect` callback like this:

```
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
```

However, this stops the canvas from responding to the resizing of the page - more specifically, the canvas aspect ratio does not follow the page dimensions when the page size increases and it does not change at all when the page size decreases.

I created two examples to illustrate the issue:

1. This example ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-0igidg?file=/plot.js)) does not have blurry canvas content because I set the canvas resolution  using the code snippet above, but does not respond to page resizing.
2. This example ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-72l79n?file=/plot.js)) responds to page resizing but the canvas content is blurry.

Do you have any suggestions how to reconcile this behavior? I have seen similar questions asked here but none of the examples actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to setting the `canvas` height and width before getting the `context`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let canvas = canvasRef.current;
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      draw(context, canvas);
    });
  }, [timer]);
```

I recommend you to use [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) since you are re-redering the component multiples times to perform an animation

**Working example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-upojf8?file=/plot.js:806-1079

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-ng0t8o?file=/plot.js) is an example (The example you linked does not have the code snippet you posted). It is still not responding when I decrease the window size.

Comment: I see is working when you open it in a new window (option), https://ng0t8o.csb.app/

Comment: I tried your example both in Firefox and Chrome and it is not working for me.